cuBLAS matrix multiplication results differ from NumPy
I'm trying to perform matrix multiplication using cuBLAS and compare the results with NumPy. However, I'm getting different results between the two. Here's my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

void printMatrix(const std::vector<double>& matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            std::cout << matrix[i * cols + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Initialize cuBLAS
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    // Matrix dimensions
    int m = 3;
    int n = 2;
    int k = 4;

    // Matrix A: shape (3, 4)
    std::vector<double> A = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0};

    // Matrix B: shape (4, 2)
    std::vector<double> B = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};

    // Matrix C: shape (3, 2)
    std::vector<double> C(m * n, 0.0);

    // Allocate device memory
    double* d_A;
    double* d_B;
    double* d_C;
    cudaMalloc(&d_A, A.size() * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc(&d_B, B.size() * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc(&d_C, C.size() * sizeof(double));

    // Copy data from host to device
    cublasSetVector(A.size(), sizeof(double), A.data(), 1, d_A, 1);
    cublasSetVector(B.size(), sizeof(double), B.data(), 1, d_B, 1);

    // Perform matrix multiplication using cuBLAS
    double alpha = 1.0;
    double beta = 0.0;
    cublasDgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, n, k, &alpha, d_A, m, d_B, k, &beta, d_C, m);

    // Copy result from device to host
    cublasGetVector(C.size(), sizeof(double), d_C, 1, C.data(), 1);

    // Print the result
    std::cout << "Result matrix C:" << std::endl;
    printMatrix(C, m, n);

    // Verify the result
    std::vector<double> expected_C = {50.0, 60.0, 114.0, 140.0, 178.0, 220.0};
    bool success = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; ++i) {
        if (std::abs(C[i] - expected_C[i]) > 1e-6) {
            success = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (success) {
        std::cout << "Test passed!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Test failed!" << std::endl;
    }

    // Free device memory
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);

    // Destroy cuBLAS handle
    cublasDestroy(handle);

    return 0;
}

The NumPy result for the same matrices is:
>>> a = np.array(list(range(1, 13))).reshape(3, 4)
>>> b = np.array(list(range(1, 9))).reshape(4, 2)
>>> np.matmul(a, b)
array([[ 50,  60],
       [114, 140],
       [178, 220]])

However, the cuBLAS result I get is:
Result matrix C:
70 80 
90 158 
184 210 
Test failed!

I've double-checked the matrix dimensions and the cublasDgemm parameters, but I can't figure out why the results are different. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong or explain the discrepancy between cuBLAS and NumPy results?

Without knowing anything about cuBLAS, you're probably dealing with some memory order issues. For instance, if you reshape using order='F' in numpy, after the matmul, you end up with array([[ 70, 158], [ 80, 184], [ 90, 210]]))... which itself looks to be your cuBLAS result but in 'F' order.

So maybe your vectors need to be initialized A = {1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 2.0, 6.0, 10.0, 3.0, 7.0, 11.0, 4.0, 8.0, 12.0} and B = {1.0, 5.0, 2.0, 6.0, 3.0, 7.0, 4.0, 8.0}? Haven't tested... it's up to you really which memory order is the "correct" interpretation

Yeah, cuBLAS uses column-major order and Numpy uses row-major, I think.

You can change the ordering with a.T and b.T (transpositions are not done eagerly). Note there is no need to use a C program for this test. You can use CuPy : use import cupy as cp and then replace np by cp and your GPU will be used :) .

There is no option to use cupy as I want to use it internally in the library I am creating. What arguments can I call cublas with to get the same result as numpy, and how can cublasSgemm be row Major?

@musako: CUBLAS (like all standard BLAS implementations, and Matlab and just about every dense linear algebra package which uses BLAS and/or LAPACK) operates in column major ("Fortran") order. There is no way to change it. You may be able to achieve what you want by telling GEMM to read in transpose order.

When you interpret your vectors as matrices for CUDA, you have to interpret A as 4x3, not 3x4 and treat it as A.T. Same with B. Then you don't need to change your input vectors and you can achieve your desired output by using transposed operations. See cublasSgemm row-major multiplication

this may also be of interest
